# How to connect an API to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm trying to connect an API to wordpress but it's my first time doing this.
I want to connect this API:https://docs.pipeless.io/reference/get-activity-actions-feed. I have been trying to use the WPgetAPI plugin but I'm confused what to put into the plugin fields, especially Object ID as I dont know what that is. Thank you for your help

I tried using the WPgetAPI because I thought it would be more simple but I have no idea what to put into each box. I don't know how to connect APIs.